# Can I enforce a classic function as a parameter instead of an arrow function with Typescript when I know that `this` is dynamic?

Tags: typescript

Some APIs want to receive functions that have to interact with `this`, so an arrow function cannot work there, e.g. for a knex subquery.

Is it possible to hint to Typescript that a function with unbound `this` is expected?

Comment: I would just rename it to avoid prefering [this]. Or I might not have understood the question.

Comment: It's about more legacy type APIs that use `this` where you have no choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: there's unfortunately no way to enforce this without requiring a lot of extra manual typing of class methods.

---

TypeScript has [`this` parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters), where the call signature of a function has an initial function parameter named `this` that specifies a constraint on the type of the `this` context needed when you call the function.  The `this` parameter is "fake" in that you don't actually pass it as the first parameter when you call the function.  For example:

```
function sayMyName(this: { name: string }) {
  console.log("Hi, my name is " + this.name + ".");
}
```

The `sayMyName()` function takes no arguments, but it can only be called if bound to an object of type `{name: string}`.  This catches the following error at compile time:

```
try {
  sayMyName(); // error, won't work unless bound
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // TypeError: this is undefined
}
```

And allows things like this:

```
sayMyName.bind({ name: "Harry Potter" })(); // okay
// Hi, my name is Harry Potter.

const hermione = {
  name: "Hermione Granger",
  speak: sayMyName
}
hermione.speak(); // okay
// Hi, my name is Hermione Granger.
```

---

So the obvious attempt at a solution to this is to make your passed-in functions specify that their `this` context should be `void`, like this:

```
function callbackCaller(cb: (this: void) => void): void {
  cb(); // okay
}
```

And this does behave the way you want with arrow/unbound functions and with `sayMyName`:

```
const arrow = () => console.log("I am an arrow function");
callbackCaller(arrow); // okay
// I am an arrow function

const anonymous = function () { console.log("I am an anonymous function"); }
callbackCaller(anonymous); // okay
// I am an anonymous function

try {
  callbackCaller(sayMyName); // error, 'this' types are incompatible
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // TypeError: this is undefined
}
```

But then you hit a problem when you try it with class methods:

```
class Weasley {
  constructor(private givenName: string) { }
  greet() {
    console.log("Hi, my name is " + this.givenName + " Weasley.");
  }
}

const ron = new Weasley("Ron");
ron.greet(); // Hi, my name is Ron Weasley.

try {
  callbackCaller(ron.greet); // oops, no compile error!!!
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // TypeError: this is undefined
}
```

TypeScript completely failed to catch that `ron.greet` has a `this` context of type `Weasley` and instead it treats it as if the `this` context is of type `any`.  Originally when `this` parameters were implemented there was going to be a `--strictThis` compiler flag to deal with this, but it was dropped.  There is an [open issue in Github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968) suggesting it be added, but for now this feature is not part of the language.  (If you want to see it added, you might want to go to that issue and give it a  or describe your use case if it's more compelling than what's there already.)

The workaround is to take any class methods you care about and *explicitly* specify `this` parameters for them.  A reasonable type to use is the [polymorphic `this` type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types), which ends up like this:

```
class Malfoy {
  constructor(private givenName: string) { }
  greet(this: this) { // <-- this parameter of type this
    console.log("It is I, " + this.givenName + " Malfoy.");
  }
}
```

That fixes the problem:

```
const draco = new Malfoy("Draco");
draco.greet(); // It is I, Draco Malfoy.

try {
  callbackCaller(draco.greet); // error, won't work unless bound
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // TypeError: this is undefined
}
```

at the expense of asking people to pepper their class methods with `this: this`.  That might be a deal-breaker for you, since there's no way you can necessarily ask others to do this.  I don't know.

---

You *might* be able to use some fancy type juggling to force TypeScript to add `this` parameters to all of a class's methods, like this:

```
type Thisify<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer R
  ? (this: Thisify<T>, ...args: A) => R : T[K]
}
const thisify = <T>(instance: T) => instance as Thisify<T>;

const reformedRon = thisify(ron);
reformedRon.greet(); // Hi, my name is Ron Weasley.
try {
  callbackCaller(reformedRon.greet); // error, won't work unless bound
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // TypeError: this is undefined
}
```

but again, you might not have the opportunity to `thisify()` someone else's class instances before their methods get passed to your `callbackCaller()` function.  I think without `--strictThis` we're kind of stuck.

---

Okay, hope that helps anyway.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?ssl=92&ssc=1&pln=78&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwIYE8Cy6ByqC2ApgBRQAWMyAXIgN6JgGE3JQBOMYA5ogL4CUdALAAoRIggJkcADaEAdDLhdiAIgASMADSJ86Bk0SVEqxAGpE5SvMZFzJ+av4BuUb1Gj2+2qPFosuEzELogA9KGIhGxscGw6AO4IAORQiIlsANaI4HLIyIgARnDgACZuEqhQEGSIxISCPmISUrIKSir1zmERACroAA6EAKLRsTRW+calhMCchGUi7iKi-th4RPIFnCXE9LbMJuqo0foACnBQUFGmAsFd4YhwGRiiD5o6egZ2xkcniOeXKLyDwiSRgViIMhRfDwMCERAAXmETX2NA00Nh8IA4mxUNxrlpfChBqgMiwMGsmG5RFC2DCEApkCSMnduo9nuhXhF3rp9PsjPl1BiGYgcXiuECQSDQJBYAgKjIZAVUBAMgBhVCKqLECAFGikCjURAANzgMBKggRAD4TWaLTRTebkeJdayHk8XosQWCIccYvFEbVLTafa1FMo1ABJRAEGNIP1wAMy6CwpyuUGapUq9WZ7UJ+Ihd0crmIaOxvEx0ZJ8AphDeqSpPEIdD4Yr5JHJuVIYJ0ZrgsPtKMx-BxuPN1sgfKd1MhJYQTPK1UarVsYhNsAttuFiIezkiB5lkcV9ebyeIad15YiLzOhVZpe51erQJEbeRUZxRApQ1JSwDQj5Mc8KcJI+D9JUMAFHI5TzlUNR1A0RKhnI4YdG+fSDCMMRsOMhoCtkYAlDMcwLEsogQDIqB5IgADqhBUXI3hIQ2bAgNAsTEP0HDGpU8JcDAxqEGA6wHKwHDcA0fBElwbCEIQUA9o04gui0KGDho2i8l8wH5KYFgTPI-GCcJhgWKYdEMYQ6COC4RJLGRoINogMRIEicIBhZyCMWoABKCBpqILmGbJ8lutymmfPyxh+UgnmMcCV43kpd6LjmK7EEFMlyVAb5wHA-TIDoYBwM0YEwHI77YQAhDVMGVNUtT1LeyFtBGnRshhwwfrhxhTIRxFwqRUqgpR1GYJqwBwExTQ+uwbFQBxXECbxiBGUJIksOwnBcJJSziFloUTD1yCIU0Kn9mpEaqJGqTGJGOh6ZYhqGQJ62mSYiDjTIk3WQFTT2fW4KpCUuKSIG7mfRNU1qAAIqDcB-SDKpwMF2VhaWt35PdiBw8jkPfVNCWeGw00ugu2bLnIq5I5IqPyW+UTYQkySpOkWQ5AB+RFKUdVwY1p3ndIl1ofcvT-lhYxPb1+TTLMg3Ulew2eP+iA9IaMDAOgAA8PQ2kiyUANoANJGEgGRWXAwCqwAujQPTG9bkQAB5XIR+TEPInvHFwRqcMAUSIAAgsGpv+2wiA+USAD8tRHar6uazrVo6J78je0aweIjaPmIHbDsK7NUvIBr+hIknxCcKweIQAcPQh5XUDV-CVHx5QJdJ+m5FObJk10vMMWBhMJcZQgtkiD3sRECUMV0wpb48pFhjRfKcVWQlSVIeTD7pRPffTwgs8Mx+zNgCkaSxOzYC5FzxSEbzDUIc1qmtSLHXi91Rf4bLJEK6IQA)